# FormType Entity : already used

Tags: symfony

I have three Entities: PurchaseOrder ,Article and ArticleOrderReference . I need the ArticleOrderReference Entity to give every Order to Article Relation an amount of an integer value.

So a purchaseOrder can have many ArticleOrderReferences. And an Article can have many ArticleOrderReferences, too.

My problem is, that every ArticleOrderReference which for example has a relation to the PurchaseOrder with the ID: 1 may only have the same Article only once. So that i couldn't choose the same Article a second time.

In my FormBuilderType:

```
$builder->add('article', 'entity', array(
         'class' => 'AcmeAppBundle:Article',
         'property' => 'name',
    ));
$builder->add('amount', 'integer');
```

How can i realize that?

PurchaseOrder:

```
class PurchaseOrder{

 /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleOrderReference", mappedBy="purchaseOrder") */
protected $purchaseOrders;
```

ArticleOrderReference:

```
/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="articles") */
protected $article;

/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PurchaseOrder", inversedBy="purchaseOrders") */
protected $purchaseOrder;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer")
 */
private $amount;
```

Article:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleOrderReference", mappedBy="article") */
protected $articles;
```

Controller:

```
$articleOrder = new ArticleOrderReference();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleOrderType(), $articleOrder);

    // process the form on POST
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {               

            $purchaseOrder = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:PurchaseOrder')
            ->find($id);

            if (!$purchaseOrder) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                        'No order found for id '.$id
                );
            }               

            $articleOrder->setPurchaseOrder($purchaseOrder); 

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($articleOrder);
            $em->flush();


            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('order', array('id' => $id)));

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UniqueEntity constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) to be sure that one `Article` is linked only once to `PurchaseOrder` through the table `ArticleOrderReference`.

You need to change your `ArticleOrderReference` entity as follow:

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// DON'T forget this use statement!!!
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity({"article", "purchaseOrder"})
 */
class ArticleOrderReference
{
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="articles") */
    protected $article;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PurchaseOrder", inversedBy="purchaseOrders") */
    protected $purchaseOrder;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="integer")
     */
    private $amount;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I added the @UniqueEntity and the use Statement in my Entity , but i still can add the same article several times.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code where you are able to add the same article several times?

Comment: Are you having the same relation 2 times in only 1 post action? If yes, when you call `$form->isValid()` it returns `true` because it doesn't exist in the database already. Can you try to post first the relation and do it a second time on a second action? (hope this is clear :) )

Comment: You mean get the $form->getData()  in the process form on post and check if there is already an existing ArticleOrderReference, before flush a new?

Comment: I mean, let's say you have your order called `fizz` and you add 1 article named `buzz`: it works ok. Then you go on the same page and add to this same order `fizz` the same object `buzz`. Does this work? (because it shouldn't)

Comment: ah ok i know what you mean. My mistake, i erased the ->setPurchaseOrder in my Controller in my first post. Can you look at my controller again, then you know, how i add my purchaseOrder to my ArticleOrderReference